# AsyncQueryHandler startQuery not executed

Tags: android, asynchronous

Well, I've got a Repository class that extends AsyncQueryHandler and I do all CRUD operation through it but occasionally the startQuery method doesn't get executed. 

Here's how it goes first I launch my application and start querying all articles from the database with a non-zero token.

If however, I tried to instantiate new anonymous AsyncQueryHandler with each query this problem doesn't occur but I need to know why it happens? 

Is it normal to use AsyncQueryHandler for multiple queries or it should be used only once like AsyncTask?

```
public class ArticlesRepository extends AsyncQueryHandler implements ArticleRepositoryActions {
    private static Context mContext;
    private int queryToken=1;
    private final int SEARCH_TOKEN=202;
    private final int CRUD_TOKEN=1001;
    private Site[]mSites=null;
    private SparseArray<Pair<`ArticlesRepositoryObserver`,Site[]>> mListeners=new SparseArray<>();
    private SparseArray<ArticlesRepositoryObserver> queryListeners=new SparseArray<>();
    private SparseArray<FeedMeArticle> allArticles;
    private final String SORT_CRITERIA=Contracts.ArticleEntry.COLUMN_DATE+" DESC";
    private final int INITIALIZE_TOKEN =101;
    private static ArticlesRepository repoInstance;
    private static ArticlesObserver observer;
    private boolean freshData;

    private ArticlesRepository(ContentResolver cr) {
        super(cr);
        if(PrefUtils.isInitialized(mContext))
            queryArticles(INITIALIZE_TOKEN);
        refreshData();
        observer=new ArticlesObserver(new android.os.Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()),this);

    }
    public static void destroyInstance(Context context) {
        if(context.equals(mContext)){
            mContext=null;
            context.getContentResolver()
                .unregisterContentObserver(observer);
            Log.d("FFFF Observer Not Exits",context.toString()+"");
        }
       // repoInstance = null;

    }

    public static ArticlesRepository getInstance(Context context){
        mContext=context;
        if(repoInstance==null)
            repoInstance=new ArticlesRepository(context.getContentResolver());
        Log.d("FFFF Observer Exist",context.toString()+"");
        context.getContentResolver()
                .registerContentObserver(Contracts.ArticleEntry.CONTENT_URI,false,observer);
        return repoInstance;
    }
    public void setListener(ArticlesRepositoryObserver mListener,Site[]sites) {
       mListeners.put(mListener.hashCode(), new Pair<>(mListener, sites));
    }

    public void unsetListener(ArticlesRepositoryObserver mListener) {
       mListeners.remove(mListener.hashCode());
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocalDataChanged() {
        Log.d("onLocalDataChanged","FFFF DataChanged");
        if(freshData){
            Log.d("onLocalDataChanged","FFFF FreshData");
            Log.d("onLocalDataChanged","FFFF listeners "+mListeners.size());

            queryArticles(INITIALIZE_TOKEN);
            freshData=false;
        }
    }


    private int insertValues(Uri uri, ContentValues[]cvs){
        for (ContentValues cv:cvs) {
            super.startInsert(CRUD_TOKEN,null,uri,cv);
        }

        return FeedMeApp.getContext().getContentResolver().bulkInsert(uri,cvs);
    }
    private void queryArticles(int token){

        if(mSites==null){
            startQuery(token,null, Contracts.ArticleEntry.CONTENT_URI,null,null,null,SORT_CRITERIA);
        }
        else {
            String []selections=new String[mSites.length];
            for(int i=0;i<selections.length;i++){
                selections[i]=mSites[i].getID()+"";
            }
            startQuery(token,null,Contracts.ArticleEntry.CONTENT_URI,null,
                    Contracts.ArticleEntry._ID+"=?",selections,SORT_CRITERIA);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could it be that there are moments when the VM thinks there are no references to the object and so dsstroys through garbage collection?

Comment: Do you mean ArticlesRepository object?
It's a singleton object .. each activity created will have a reference to this ArticlesRepository so I don't think so

Comment: I did mean the ArticlesRepository and after your clarification I think my proposition is wrong.